# Trying to use Excel VBA to copy/paste rows onto form, saving form in between rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that serves as source data for another Excel-based form (not a Userform, just a formatted spreadsheet). The source file has anywhere from 2-40 rows of data - starting from row 18 - and each row needs to be copied into the form and saved separately, i.e. 15 rows from the Source file equates to 15 distinct Form files.

Each cell within the row must be copied separately and pasted to specific cells on the Form. The Source form contains Clients and their relevant info. I am trying to use a macro on the Form to automatically pull line items from the Source file, save the Form as the client's name in a specified folder, and continue until a blank row is reached on the Source file. I have some basic VBA experience, but have little knowledge of loops, variables, or functions, which seem to be my best course of action here.

Here's what I have so far. All I've been able to accomplish is the copy/pasting of the first row from the Source file.

```
Range("B18").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Form.xls").Activate
Range("F7:K7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("Source.xls").Activate
Range("C18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Processing Form.xls").Activate
Range("D8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("Source.xls").Activate
Range("D18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Processing Form.xls").Activate
Range("H29").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("Source.xls").Activate
Range("E18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Processing Form.xls").Activate
Range("E29").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Windows("Source.xls").Activate
Range("F18").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Processing Form.xls").Activate
Range("D33").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range(“F7:K7”).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
```

I can't even get my macro to save the Form by the client's name. I also know that my extensive use of "Range" and "Select" will slow my code down to a crawl, I just don't know how to make it more efficient. I've tried using a reference cell to that tells the macro which row of the Source file to copy but haven't had any luck down that road either. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple demo:

**Note: Not Tested**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToForm()

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbForm As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsForm As Worksheet
Dim formpath As String, foldertosavepath as string
Dim lrow As Long, i As Integer

Set wbSource = Thisworkbook '~~> assuming you write your code in Source.xls
Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("NameOfYourSheet") '~~> put the source sheet name

'~~> put the path where your form template is saved here
formpath = "C:\Users\Username\FolderName\Processing Form.xls"
'~~> put the path where you want to save individual updated forms.
foldertosavepath = "C:\Users\Username\FolderDestination\"

With wsSource
    '~~> get the number of rows with data
    lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lrow < 18 Then Msgbox "No data for transfer": Exit Sub
    For i = 18 to lrow
        Set wbForm = Workbooks.Open(formpath) '~~> open the form
        Set wsForm = wbForm.Sheets("Sheetname") '~~> put the form sheet name
        '~~> proceed with the copying
        .Range("B" & i).Copy: wsForm.Range("F7:K7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValue
        .Range("C" & i).Copy: wsForm.Range("D8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("D" & i).Copy: wsForm.Range("H29").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("E" & i).Copy: wsForm.Range("E29").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Range("F" & i).Copy: wsForm.Range("D33").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        '~~> Save the form using the client name, I assumed it is in B?
        wbForm.SaveAs foldertosavepath & .Range("B" & i).Value & ".xls"
        wbForm.Close True
        Set wbForm = Nothing
        Set wsForm = Nothing
   Next
End With

End Sub
```

In above code, I assumed that `Form.xls` is the same as `Processing Form.xls`.
This should give you the logic.
I hope this get's you started.
This is not test as I've noted, so if you encounter errors, comment it out.

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much! The only issue I am left with is getting the macro to paste only the values into the form to comply with formatting necessities. I've tried adding .Value as seen below but this results in an error: "Run-time error '1004': Copy method of Range class failed"

`.Range("C" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("D8").Value`

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: When I tried implementing your changes I received a run-time error '438': "Object doesn't support this property or method." This is the code I used when receiving that error: `.Range("C" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("D8").PasteSpecialxlPasteValues`

Comment: I then tried adding parentheses: `.Range("C" & i).Copy wsForm.Range("D8").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)` and received Run-Time error 1004: "Unable to get the PasteSpecial property of the Range class."

Any ideas on what's causing the problem?

Comment: Take note of the `:`. It denotes new line.

Answer (score 0):

***You are frequently activating the workbooks. that's your code slows down..Below code will work faster***

```
Sub test()
Dim dwb As Workbook
Dim swb As Workbook

Set dwb = Workbooks("Form.xls")
Set swb = Workbooks("Source.xls")
Set awb = Workbooks("Processing Form.xls")

    With swb
    .ActiveSheet.Range("B18").Copy Destination:=dwb.Sheet1.Range("F7:K7")
    .ActiveSheet.Range("C18").Copy Destination:=awb.Sheet1.Range("D8")
    .ActiveSheet.Range("D18").Copy Destination:=awb.Sheet1.Range("H29")
    .ActiveSheet.Range("e18").Copy Destination:=awb.Sheet1.Range("E29")
    .ActiveSheet.Range("F18").Copy Destination:=awb.Sheet1.Range("D33")
    End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help steer you in the right direction:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 10
    With Range("A" & i)
        .Copy Workbooks("ToWorkbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i + 9)
        .Copy Workbooks("ToAnother.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i + 8)
        .Copy Workbooks("AnotherOne.xlsx").Worksheets("SheetA").Range("D" & i + 2)
    End With
Next i
```

`i To 10` is used as a counter to loop through the rows in the source workbook.
For each `i`, you're taking the range from column A (i.e., `with` this, do something), copying and pasting it into different cells in different workbooks. In the first round, Range("A1") is being copied into 3 different workbooks at Range("B10"), Range("C9") and Range("D3"), respectively. The next turn, Range("A2") from the source book is going to be copied and pasted into the same destination workbooks from last time, but in Range("B11"), Range("C10") and Range("D4"). It's just a matter of finding the pattern for the different forms you need to paste into.